# How to get best selling products using wp_query woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I want to get Best selling Products on Home page. I am using Below query But this is not getting best selling products from all categories.

If I put best selling product short code that is working but custom structure could not get those products.
These My Query Function..

```
function get_product_posts_hp()
{
    wp_reset_query();
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 12,
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
        'meta_key' => 'total_sales',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'DESC',
    );
    return new WP_Query($args);
}

Thanks In Advance..
```

Comment: Why removing the acceptance on this answer below that works? Is there something wrong? You can always add comment on the answer, explaining if something is wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code works globally… I have tried with the following function code:

```
function get_product_posts_hp(){
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'posts_per_page' => 12,
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'meta_key' => 'total_sales',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'DESC',
    ) );

    echo '<p>Count: '. $query->post_count ; '</p>';

    if($query->have_posts()) :
        while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();

            echo '<p>' . get_the_title() . ' (';
            echo get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'total_sales', true) . ')</p>';

        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
}
```

And I get 12 products titles displayed by total sales DESC.